# Multi variable Mellin transformation and its inverse transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, mellin-transform

First of all, I know Fourier transformation and its inverse transformation for multivariable. i.e.,  The multivariable Fourier transformation of $f(\vec{x})$ and inverse Fourier transformation of $g(\vec{\zeta})$ is given by
\begin{align}
  &\mathcal{F} (f) := \int  e^{-2 \pi i \vec{x} \cdot \vec{\zeta}} f(\vec{x}) d\vec{x} \\
  &\mathcal{F}^{-1} (g):= \int  e^{2\pi i \vec{x} \cdot \vec{\zeta} } g(\vec{\zeta}) d \vec{\zeta}
\end{align}

**Now I want to know the Multi-variable extension of Mellin transformation and its inverse transformation.**

For the single variable case, I know the following definitions from Fourier and its inverse transformation.

Let $f(t)$ be a function defined on the positive real axis $0<t<\infty$. The Mellin transformation $\mathcal{M}$ is the operation mapping the function $f$ into the function $F$ defined on the complex by the relation
\begin{align}
    \mathcal{M}[f;s]= F(s) := \int_0^{\infty} f(t) t^{s-1} dt
  \end{align}
In general the integral does exists only for complex values $s=a+jb$ such that $a_1<a<a_2$, where $a_1, a_2$ depend on the function $f(t)$ to transform. Denote this by $S(a_1,a_2)$ and call the strip.

And the Inverse Melline transformation is given by
\begin{align}
  f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi j} \int_{a-j\infty}^{a+j\infty} F(s) t^{-s} ds
\end{align}
where the integration is along a vertical line through $\operatorname{Re}[s]=a$.

Comment: The Mellin transform is just the Fourier transform of $f(e^{-u}) e^{-\sigma \cdot u}$ so where are you stuck

Comment: @reuns, I know the relation between them. But the tricky part is its generalization to multivariable. For example, I know $\mathcal{M}[f(x);a+ib] = \mathcal{F}[f(e^{-x}) e^{-a x};b]$, but it does not make sense to change $x \mapsto \vec{x}$, since $f(e^{-\vec{x}})$ is not well-defined. i.e., $e^{-\vec{x}}$ is a tricky part. Further more the decomposition of $s=a+ib$ to its general $\vec{s}$ seems not unclear to me as well.

Comment: No. Just try with 2 variables you'll see why there is  nothing weird happening

Comment: Hello @reuns,  I just make an answer post below based on your comments.  Am I understanding your comments properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the multivariable Fourier transformation in more detail. i.e., Fourier transformation of $f(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ into $\mathcal{F}(f)(\zeta_1, \cdots, \zeta_n)$ is given by

\begin{align}
  \mathcal{F}(f) = \int e^{-2 \pi i (\sum_i x_i \zeta_i)} f(x_1, \cdots, x_n) dx_1 \cdots dx_n
\end{align}

From
\begin{align}
\mathcal{M}[f(x);s=a+2 \pi ib] = \mathcal{F}[f(e^{-x})e^{-ax};b]
\end{align}
with the comment of @reuns, extend $s$ to $\vec{s}$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{M}[f(x_1, \cdots, x_n);\vec{s}] = \mathcal{F}[f(e^{-x_1}, e^{-x_2}, \cdots, e^{-x_n}) ; \vec{b}] 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(e^{-x_1}, \cdots, e^{-x_n}) e^{-\vec{s} \cdot \vec{x}} dx_1 \cdots dx_n
\end{align}
Now back to $t$, for one variatble case using $t=e^{-x}, dt = - e^{-x}$, I have $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) t^{s-1} dt$, hence
\begin{align}
\mathcal{M}[f(x_1, \cdots, x_n);\vec{s}] = \int_0^{\infty} f(t_1, \cdots, t_n) t_1^{s_1 -1} \cdots t_n^{s_n-1} dt_1 \cdots dt_n
\end{align}
and similar arguement can be applied to inverse Mellin as well. i.e.,
the inverse Mellin transformation can be achieved via
\begin{align}
f(t_1, \cdots, t_n) = (\frac{1}{2 \pi i})^n \int_{a_n - i \infty}^{a_n + i\infty} \cdots \int_{a_1 - i \infty}^{a_1 + i\infty} F(s_1, \cdots, s_n) t_1^{-s_1} \cdots t_n^{-s_n} ds_1 \cdots ds_n
\end{align}
where the integration is along a vertical line through $\operatorname{Re}[s_i]=a_i$.

Comment: That's correct, except for the $1/2i\pi$ and your $\mathcal{F}$ should be a Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}$. The Fourier transform is when putting the real part of $e^{-s.x}$ with $f$ and putting $\Im(s)$ for $b$. And your $F(s_1,\ldots)$ is $\mathcal{M}[f]$.